# When the convolution is a Schwartz function?

Tags: convolution

If $u$ is integrable and $v$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ ($1\leq p\leq \infty$) then $u*v\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$
(Reference: Adapted Wavelet Analysis by Mladen)

If $u$ is Schwartz function and $v$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $u*v$ is a Schwartz function?

Answer (score 0):

No. In generally, we have the following result
$$
L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\ast \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) \quad \forall p\in[1,+\infty]
$$
See exercise 3.18 - Mitrea, D. Distribucions, Partial Differential Equations, and Harmonic Analysis.

For a counterexample: [How to show convolution of an $L^p$ function and a Schwartz function is a Schwartz function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239027/how-to-show-convolution-of-an-lp-function-and-a-schwartz-function-is-a-schwar)